# Extension of ImageView crashes on construction in Android test project

Tags: java, android, imageview, extends

I am trying to test a class I have created that extends ImageView.  It crashed on construction, apparently before running any code (stepping through with the debugger didn't reach any breakpoints in the construction code).  As a sanity check I created this class:

```
package com.blah.thing;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DoNothing extends ImageView {

    public DoNothing(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public DoNothing(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public DoNothing(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

It STILL crashes.  I am calling it from an Activity which also basically does nothing (so far):

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        DoNothing dn = new DoNothing(context);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
```

This activity is in an Android test project alongside the main project ... is there something I need to do to fix the dependencies or something?  By the way I am importing all the packages I need to refer to DoNothing, Context and so on.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmmmm ... Try declaring your custom `ImageView` in a layout and inflating it instead of just creating it. Also, post any exceptions you got.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
DoNothing dn = new DoNothing(this);
```

instead of

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();         
DoNothing dn = new DoNothing(context);
```

on onCreate(...)